# Proportion of patients in different strata

Tags: r

I am trying to distribute 20 patients into 4 strata. The covariates are jointly distributed. Below is my code, along with the error. Can anyone help me debug this?

```
runif(20)
if (0<u<3/20) then {i1} =1  
if (3/20<u<14/20) then {i2} =2
if (14/20<u<19/20) then {i3} =3
if (19/20<u<20/20) then {i4} =4
```

```
Error: unexpected '<' in "if (0<u<"**
```

Comment: You cannot apply two `<` conditions in one statement simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cut` function to assign your strata:

```
breaks <- c(0, 3/20, 14/20, 19/20, 20)
labels <- 1:4
set.seed(7)
x <- runif(20)
stratum <- cut(x, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
df <- data.frame(cbind(x, stratum))
df
            x stratum
1  0.98890930       4
2  0.39774545       2
3  0.11569778       1
4  0.06974868       1
5  0.24374939       2
6  0.79201043       3
```

As AnilGoya mentioned, you have clean up your comparison operators.